# Can screen readers on all Xamarin platforms announce the checked state of a standard Xamarin CheckBox?

Tags: ios, xamarin, accessibility, voiceover, talkback

I created a new Xamarin app from a Visual Studio template, added a `CheckBox` with an accessible name set through use of `AutomationProperties.LabeledBy`, and made the code public at https://github.com/gbarkerz/XamarinCheckBox. If I build and run the Windows UWP version, the Windows UI Automation accessible representation of the `CheckBox` seems complete. If I build and run the Android version, the TalkBack screen reader announces the expected name and checked state of the `CheckBox`, as shown in an image attached here. The image shows the Android TalkBack screen reader announcing the following when navigating to an unchecked Xamarin `CheckBox`: "not ticked, Tick Box for Crane operator ready:"

[image: TalkBack announcing the name and state of a CheckBox.]

If I build and run the iOS version, the VoiceOver screen reader only announces "Button" when navigating to the `CheckBox` as shown in an image attached here. The image shows the iOS VoiceOver screen reader announcing the following when navigating to a checked Xamarin `CheckBox`: "Button".

[image: Voiceover not announcing the name or state of a CheckBox.]

VoiceOver does not announce the name or checked state of the `CheckBox`. I can work around the name issue by replacing my use of `AutomationProperties.LabeledBy` with `AutomationProperties.Name`, but that doesn't help with conveying the `CheckBox` checked state. Would anyone know the recommended steps to have the name and checked state of Xamarin CheckBoxes announced by screen readers on all of Windows, Android, and iOS?

Comment: CheckBoxes are not a normal thing on iOS. So Xamarin.Forms adds them as custom Buttons. On Android CheckBoxes derive from Buttons natively. If it is just a single item you may want to consider using a Switch instead. As for your voice over issue, you are probably stuck with these CheckBoxes being called buttons.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll take a closer look at using a Switch on iOS. Given that my app's a Xamarin app, I'd hoped that a Xamarin CheckBox would work by default with the screen readers on Android and iOS, but this doesn't seem to be the case. As a temporary workaround on iOS, I hacked the CheckBox name to include the CheckBox's checked state, but I'll need to replace this before long.